# How do I prevent first element of array to be selected as value for select option

Tags: angular

I am currently using `ngFor` to loop over a `senders` array. My goal is to display the `name` field of the object and also, when the option is selected, the field `id` is passed to the component instead. For some reason. when I reload the page, it shows the first element of the `senders` array as a default value. I have tried `option disabled`, tried resetting the select value after submitting, but the input field keeps selecting the first element. I also realized that the binding is not successful with the component and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Below is the HTML:

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="providers.provider_id != ''; else noItems">
                <ng-container *ngIf=" providers$ | async; let _provider">
                    <form (ngSubmit)=onSubmit()>
                        <div class="currency">
                            <label for="send">Select {{providers.send_currency}} account</label>
                            <select name="send " id="field " class="select-field" [(ngModel)]="senderId">
                                <option value="" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select sender {{providers.send_currency}} account</option>
                                <option *ngFor="let sender of senders " [value]="sender.id">{{ sender.name }}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="currency">
                            <label for="receive">Select {{providers.receive_currency}} account</label>
                            <select name="receive " id="field " class="select-field" [(ngModel)]="receiverId">
                                <option value=""selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select receiver {{providers.receive_currency}} account</option>
                                <option *ngFor="let receiver of receivers" [value]="receiver.id">{{ receiver.name }}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="name">
                            <input type="text " id="field " placeholder="Amount " [(ngModel)]="amount " name="amount ">
                        </div>
                        <div class="purchase">
                            <button type="submit " style="padding: 10px 10px; ">Make purchase</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
```

Below is the Ts component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-purchase',
  templateUrl: './purchase.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./purchase.component.css']
})
export class PurchaseComponent {

  public providers:providers={provider_id:"", provider_name:"", send_currency:"", receive_currency:"", sell_rate:0}
  providers$: Observable<providers> | undefined;
  accounts$: Observable<Account[]> | undefined;

  senders: Account[] = [{id:"",user_id:"", name:"", currency:""}]
  receivers: Account[] = [{id:"",user_id:"", name:"", currency:""}]
  senderDetail:Account= {user_id:"", name:"", currency:"", id:""}
  receiverDetail:Account= {user_id:"", name:"", currency:"", id:""}
  senderId : string | undefined
  receiverId : string | undefined
  amount:string = ""
  displayModal = false

  constructor(
    private purchaseStore: PurchaseStoreService,
    private accountStore: AccountStoreService,
    private transferService: TransferRemoteService,
    private messageService:MessageService,
    @Inject(ACCOUNT_SERVICE_TOKEN) private accountService: AccountsRemoteService,
  ) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.senderId = undefined
    this.receiverId = undefined
    var userId = localStorage.getItem("user_id")!
    this.accountService.getAccountsForUserID(userId).subscribe(
      {
        next : res  => {
          this.accountStore.setAccount(res.data!)
        },
        error : err => console.log(err)
      }
    )
    this.providers$ = this.purchaseStore.getProvidersAsObservable();
    this.providers = this.purchaseStore.getProviders()  
    this.accountStore.getAccount().subscribe(
      {
        next: (account) => {
          this.senders = account.filter((element) => element.currency == this.providers.send_currency)
          this.receivers = account.filter(element => element.currency == this.providers.receive_currency)
      },
      error: err => console.log(err)
    }
    )
  }

  onSubmit(){
    var transferRequestBody = {
// this is empty after select
      sender_account_id: this.senderId,
//this is empty after select
      receiver_account_id: this.receiverId,
      amount: Number(this.amount)*100,
      rate: this.providers.sell_rate*100,
      provider_name: this.providers.provider_name
    } as transfer;
    this.transferService.makeTransfer(transferRequestBody).subscribe(
      {
        next : res  => {
          console.log(res.data)
          this.displayModal = !this.displayModal;
          this.messageService.add({
            severity: 'success',
            summary: 'Success',
            detail: 'Purchase made successfully!',
          });
        },
        error : err => {
          this.displayModal = !this.displayModal;
          this.messageService.add({
            severity: 'success',
            summary: 'Success',
            detail: 'Purchase failed!',
          });
          console.log(err)}
      }
    )
    this.senderDetail.name=""
    this.receiverDetail.name = ""
    this.amount = ""
    this.senderId = ""
    this.receiverId = ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial value of the senderId property to null instead of undefined in the PurchaseComponent class. You should have something like this:

```js
export class PurchaseComponent {

  ...

  senderId : string | null = null;
  receiverId : string | null = null;
  amount:string = ""
  displayModal = false

  ...

}
```